# CheckBox in jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jcheckbox

I've added a checkbox to rows on my table, but unfortunately I'm unable to select/deselect them.

I'm using an own Table Model that I got on internet.

Table Model's code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
/**************/

public class ModeloTabela extends AbstractTableModel {
    private ArrayList linhas = null;
    private String [] colunas = null;

    public ModeloTabela(ArrayList lin, String[] col){
        setLinhas(lin);
        setColunas(col);
    }
    public ArrayList getLinhas(){
        return linhas;

    }
    public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados){
        linhas = dados;
    }
    public String[] getColunas(){
        return colunas;
    }
    public void setColunas(String [] nomes){
        colunas = nomes;
    }
    public int getColumnCount(){
        return colunas.length;
    }
    public int getRowCount(){
        return linhas.size();
    }
    public String getColumnCount (int numCol){
        return colunas[numCol];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int numCol){
        Object[] linha = (Object[])getLinhas().get(numLin);
        return linha[numCol];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this Method will fill the Table:

```
public void PreencheTabela(String sql, JTable jt1, JTextField j1){
        c.conexao();
        ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
    String [] Colunas = new String[] {"STATUS", "ID", "FABRICANTE", "FORNECEDOR", "NOME", "CATEGORIA", "DATA DO CADASTRO", " CODIGO DE BARRAS", "QUANTIDADE"};

    c.executaSQL(sql);
    try { 
        c.rs.first();
        do{
        dados.add(new Object[]{c.rs.getInt("prod_id"),c.rs.getString("prod_fabricante"),c.rs.getString("prod_fornecedor"),c.rs.getString("prod_nome"),
            c.rs.getString("prod_categoria"),c.rs.getDate("prod_datacadastro"),c.rs.getString("prod_codbarras"), c.rs.getInt("est_quantidade")});
        j1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }while(c.rs.next());

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro!\n"+ex.getMessage());
    }
    ModeloTabela modelo = new ModeloTabela(dados, Colunas);
    jt1.setModel(modelo);
}
```

Which code can I use? Also, where do I put this code??

Comment: `I've added a checkbox to rows on my table,` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255379/add-checkbox-to-jtable) so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do it. But on this question, I have another question ):

Comment: Have a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Answer (score 2):

> but unfortunately I'm unable to select/deselect them.

You didn't implement the `setValueAt(...)` method in your TableModel so the value can never be updated in the model.

> I'm using an own Table Model that I got on internet.

Why are you using a custom TableModel? You can use the `DefaultTableModel`. It implements the `setValueAt(...)` method correctly. It also has an `addRow(..)` method that allows you to dynamically update the model.

Are you actually storing `Boolean` objects in the TableModel? I don't see you using `getBoolean()` to get the data from your ResultSet. The default renderers/editors for a check box will only be used when you have Boolean data in the column.

Also take a look at: [Can't create column with checkboxes in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221047/cant-create-column-with-checkboxes-in-jtable/32230173#32230173) for a better implementation of the `getColumnClass()` method.

If you insist on using your custom TableModel, then take a look at the Swing tutorial link you were given in your last question. It shows and example of implementing the `setValueAt()` method.

Comment: I think you mean `setValueAt` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, was just double checking... :)